# Find and convert symbol to anchors

Tags: php, regex, anchor

Sorry if this question is a duplicate of another ones, I couldn't find it :-/

Hey guys, I am guessing it's a simple regexp question but help me out will you? Regexps are always look so complicated to me :-)

in this example :

> @2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sit
>   amet quam ante, sit amet consectetur ante. Ut non urna in quam
>   adipiscing consectetur et sed lorem. Donec venenatis vehicula
>   porttitor.

I want to convert @2 to

```
<a href="#2">@2</a>
```

but user may type it like "@2Lorem.." without space or it may be @38427. how can i grab '@' symbol and numbers after it and convert to anchor?

Edit: and also @ may be in the middle of text it may not always be in beginning.

Comment: so `@2lorem` should be `<a name="#2">@2</a>lorem`?

Comment: @AkainuLionheart. And what all you can have in place of `@2`? I mean if it is only `@2` to be replaced, then there is no big deal.

Comment: there could be many @s. in one post : "@2 you got it! @4 nah.."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/@(\d+)/', '<a name="#$1">@$1</a>', $string)
```

sample:

```
php > $x = 'abc @234lorem def';
php > echo preg_replace('/@(\d+)/', '<a name="#$1">@$1</a>', $x);
abc <a name="#234">@234</a>lorem def

\d - any digit
+ - one or more times
```

Comment: this both v01pe and yours is working great! but it only gets one digit after @, @ could have one or more digits should i put d++ ?

Comment: Hahaha i am terribly sorry, i was using print_r to show result (was tried preg_match). it put 1 to end of the string. I feel so stupid, thank you very much Marc B!

Answer (score 2):

find: `@([0-9]+)`
replace: `<a href="#$1">@$1</a>`

```
preg_replace('/@([0-9]+)/', '<a name="#$1">@$1</a>', $string);
```